# Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, execution-time

I upload an excel file with 1000 rows,  by default I have just 2 min in execution time, with that time I can upload 400 records.
I get this error `Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded`

How i can modify this period in yii2 framework ?

Comment: If you're able to use a modern browser you could upload it in chunks with ajax.

Comment: Add this line at the top of your script:    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You need to change that in the php.ini:

```
max_execution_time = 500
```

or in your  php script:

```
set_time_limit(500); //
```

Comment: could you tell me where in yii2 advanced template  php.ini file? thanks.

Comment: @cruim   php.ini is not in yii2 templatee  .. but in php configuration file ..normally is in the dir where is stored the php code  (depend by OS) ..   the best way for find php.ini is run  <?php phpinfo(); ?>   . or you can add to your php code ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes

Comment: I have a problem with download excel file from site. You mean 'add to script' like that ` <?php
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); 
    $gridColumns = [` I added in script in view but nothing changed.

Comment: @cruim  post  a new proper question   for what you need  and eventually comment me the link .. (answer in comment is not easy) ..

Comment: Add `set_time_limit(500);` in php script, e.g. `/config/main-local.php`